# google place api pass multiple types in web service api

Tags: google-maps

I am using google place api to to search near by results of lan long but i am not able to pass mutliple types. Is it not possible to pass multiple search types ?

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=30.642550,76.817336&key=examplekey&sensor=false&radius=200&types=restaurant
```

I have already tried passing type as types=atm|restaurant or types as types=atm,restaurant it does not works.

Comment: Only one type may be specified (if more than one type is provided, all types following the first entry are ignored). As stated in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search).

Answer (score 0):

From what I could see on the web, it seems that

> Google are deprecating multiple types for Place Searches

[as you can see on this github issue.](https://github.com/maximn/google-maps/issues/72)